# "object reference not set to an instance of an object " getting an error?

Tags: object, reference, set

I am making an app and getting this error. I don't know why this is not navigating to the desired page. There is my code.

```
  public MainPage()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         while (appsetting.Contains("Roll_Number"))
         {
             txtBx_Login.Text = appsetting["Roll_Number"].ToString();
             Btn_Login1_Click(null,null);
         }
    }
 private void Btn_Login1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string id = txtBx_Login.Text;

            id = id.Substring(0, 4);

            switch (id)
            {
               case "1234": NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PrincipalPivotPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); break; // While I am debugging the error is showing here ....??***

               case "0820": NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/StudentsPivotPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); break; // While I am debugging the error is showing here ....??**

               default: MessageBox.Show("Oops..!!Correct Your Enrollment Number...."); break;
            }                
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I don't know why this happening can anyone explain ...??

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that /PrincipalPivotPage.xaml and /StudentsPivotPage.xaml exist relative to you application directory...?

```
new Uri("/PrincipalPivotPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
```

Comment: and it is navigating to that page but after navigation it is showing above error ...any idea ..??